# jQuery BxSlider not working on ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the bxslider to work on this page in ie7 http://redbarn.blackdogstaging.com/ it works fine in ie8 and newer browsers. It seems as if the script isn't loading. I'm not too good with js / jquery so anything will help. Heres the code I'm using:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider1').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            pager: true,
            controls: true,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            captions: false,
            pause: 6000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Link you have given is working fine in ie7, be specific

Answer (score 0):

New BxSlider (BxSlider v4.0) has some syntax fail. I have fixed it for IE7. You can use that fixed version.

Good works.

[Fixed BxSlider](http://www.zaferhangul.com/jquery.bxslider.js)

Answer (score 0):

If script doesn't work try to add `$jQ = jQuery.noConflict();` and replace all `$` -> `$jQ`
here is ready script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jQ(document).ready(function(){
        $jQ('#slider1').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            pager: true,
            controls: true,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            captions: false,
            pause: 6000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Yes and one more thing if it doesn't show good in IE7 try to apply folowing CSS to the  `<ul>` from slide

```
*+html .ul-class {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```